# GNOME extension 'window list' remains after uninstalled

Tags: uninstall, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

A while ago I enabled an extension. Realizing I didn't like the look of it, I tried to uninstall it on the webpage https://extensions.gnome.org/
But, surprisingly, it is still not gone yet.

Hence I resorted to using this command

```
sudo rm -r window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
```

By then, I assumed I had uninstalled the extension [window list](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/). No. It is still at the bottom of my screen:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Ubuntu version 17.04, GNOME shell version 3.24.2 . The command was used in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

**Edit:**

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions$ locate -r /window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com$
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions$ ls
alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com            places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com                screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com        user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com               windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com      workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 ships with with many "*official*" GNOME extensions by default, *Window List* is one of them. These extensions are not stored in
`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` but in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

It is **not at all recommended** to run `rm` in a system folder as this could break things within GNOME shell, or on the next package upgrade reinstall the extension. Try to disable it instead using GNOME Tweak Tool or from https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and then log out and log in again.

If you're **absolutely positive** about removing the extension you'll have to run the `rm` command in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` (First check whether it's there using `ls`).

Comment: Consider that this could break things within gnome-shell package, or on the next package upgrade reinstall the extension.  That's a risk you run though.

Comment: @ThomasWard True that! I'm adding a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Indeed, the directory is in the path `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Unfortunately, removing the extension still didn't work! Sigh. Some of the comments on the extension page also suggest inability to disable it. Please take a look there.

Comment: @VeiiXhen Are you by any chance logged into a "GNOME Classic" session? If so, try to log in to a normal GNOME session.

Comment: @pomsky Pretty sure I wasn't. As a matter of fact I have been using gnome default on day 1. But well, it fixed itself right after I logged out and logged back in again! Looks like a bug? If it is, should I file a report or something?

Comment: @VeiiXhen I don't think so. Many times after installing/uninstalling an extension one needs to logout and login again or restart GNOME shell (not possible in Wayland) in order to properly load/unload the extension. So it's kinda expected I believe.

Comment: @pomsky Arhh... Then I was the one acting all nervous and freaked out. This question should never have existed.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue just now, turns out I was logging into Gnome classic instead of regular Gnome – that's why the extension wasn't going away even after disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the metadata.json file in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com$`
and restart the system, it will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The extension is not stored in
`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` but in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

The following command should delete the folder containing the extension and solve the problem:

```
sudo rm -r '/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com'
```

In the above command, the last item in the path is the name of the folder that contains the extension.